# Passing multiple values to :not() jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to filter multiple values from an event in jQuery.

At the moment I have:

```
.filter(":not(.element)")
```

How would I go about adding more things to filter? I've tried:

```
.filter(":not(.element, .another, .etc)")
```

and

```
.filter(":not(.element)").filter(":not(.another)").filter(":not(.etc)")
```

and

```
.filter(":not(.element),:not(.another),:not(.etc)")
```

With no luck. What do I need to do?

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers - I've find another solution to my problem that avoids having to do what I've asked in the question, but evidently I wasn't doing something properly in my code since the solutions posted work. I will mark an answer as correct, many thanks.

Comment: It does work - http://jsfiddle.net/DKbPK/

Comment: All your samples should work, theres something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is working, you just need to separate each element using a comma (,) in the `:not()` selector.

You can check the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LVUMs/

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is working. http://jsbin.com/uyayot/edit#javascript,html

I tried:

```
$('div').not('#div2,#div4').each ( function () {
    alert ( $(this).attr ('id' ) );
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) by chaining it. Like this

```
$('yourElement').not(':even').not('.SomeMore').not('.fewmore')
```

Comment: Even though it would work - it doesn't explain why other OP's attempts failed